# How to get Android Support library 20 revision in sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-support-library

I'm using Android Studio. Everything was going good but I updated Android support library to 22 revision and my application UI is changed and In some Activities app is crash.

I want to downgrade the version of Android support library from 22 revision to 20 revision in SDK so I uninstalled Android support library but when I install it every time 22 revision is installed.

How can I install 20 revision of Android support library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check inside the sdk folder in your pc.

```
 androidsdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support
```

For each support library you will find all versions available.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

Pay attention.
If you use the v20+, you have to use the api 21+ to compile your project.

Comment: "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'" - Is it possible to specify those versions in Eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

In your app's module there is a build.gradle file. Inside that you will see something like:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:xx.x.x'`

This is how you dictate which support library is used when compiling the app. You will need to have the version you choose installed in your SDK manager.

Comment: i did the same but i get errors:- Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.                                                       Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.            Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.                         Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.

Comment: Change your `compiledSdkVersion` to 21 and `targetSdkVersion` to 21. Make sure you have it downloaded in the SDK manager as well.